# Upload multipart file using camel rest DSL

Tags: java, rest, file-upload, apache-camel, multipartform-data

I wish to upload a multipart file which includes a file and some json and output the file to a local folder using camel rest dsl.

I am using a processor in the route to split the multipart request into the parts using HttpServletRequest.getPart() however I receive the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No multipart config for servlet
```

I have added a MultiPartFilter to the servlet and have tried both with and without a multipartResolver bean. When I'm debugging the processor I can see that the HttpServletRequest request object is actually a MultiPartFilter$Wrapper but the exception is still occurring.

Upload form in html page:

```
<html>
<body>
    <form action="http://localhost:8080/content/publish" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <p>
            Json: <input type="text" name="json"/>
        </p>
        <p>
            File: <input type="file" name="uploadedFile" multiple="true" />
        </p>
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Route to process the request:

```
rest("/content").post("/publish").consumes("multipart/form-data").route().process(new MultipartProcessor()).to("file:src/main/resources/testUpload");
```

The request:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryOAiLMJtrA2g4CB32
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="json"

{ "json" : "test" }
------WebKitFormBoundaryOAiLMJtrA2g4CB32
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="uploadedFile"; filename="test.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain


------WebKitFormBoundaryOAiLMJtrA2g4CB32--
```

MultipartProcessor:

```
@Override
public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
    HttpMessage message = exchange.getIn(HttpMessage.class);
    HttpServletRequest request = message.getRequest();
    Part file = request.getPart("uploadedFile");
    // then process to output file
}
```

In web.xml:

```
  <servlet>
    <display-name>Camel Http Transport Servlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>CamelServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.camel.component.servlet.CamelHttpTransportServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>CamelServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <filter>
        <filter-name>MultipartFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.MultiPartFilter</filter-class>
   </filter>  

   <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>MultipartFilter</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>CamelServlet</servlet-name>  
   </filter-mapping>
```

Multipart resolver in camel-context.xml:

```
<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver"/>
```

Comment: for me  exchange.getIn(HttpMessage.class); returns null always

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the request is multipart, if it is add your config to the request:

```
if (request.getContentType() != null && request.getContentType().startsWith("multipart/form-data")) {
  request.setAttribute(Request.__MULTIPART_CONFIG_ELEMENT, MULTI_PART_CONFIG);
}
```

Source : http://jetty.4.x6.nabble.com/jetty-users-Enable-multipart-support-in-Handlers-under-Embedded-jetty-without-XML-configs-or-WebAppCt-td4959804.html

Comment: Thanks, that has fixed my original issue of the IllegalStateException however now I am receiving an IOException: Missing content for multipart request.. Guessing something is reading the request before it gets to the processor but I'm not sure what.

Comment: @Sian, I am also facing the same issue of "IOException: Missing content for multipart request". Did you find any solution?